# How to Create Frontend User Profiles in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, user-profile

I had a look at this post - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9775/how-to-edit-a-user-profile-on-the-front-end and it looks like it works well. Is the way it is written best practice or did it change with newer WP versions?

I would like to know what the best way would be to create a frontend user profile for the WP users. They must be able to edit it in frontend and view it/visit it.

I am new to WP and PHP so please explain the code or have comments in the code so that I can get a general idea of how it is put together.

I would like to code it myself from scratch so please no user-plugin recommendations like buddypress.

Comment: Users of the files and users inside WP admin panel are not the same ones. How the "front-end user" is suppose to edit files? Through FTP or inside WP panel editor?

Comment: @pkolawa what do you mean by the users not being the same? All users registering on the site are users on the site, just with different roles. Frontend users must be able to edit their profiles outside the WP backend panel like in the link. Let me know if this is unclear.